# boost::locale::conv::from_utf doesn't work on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc, boost, boost-locale

I am trying to convert utf-8 string with special quote symbols to Latin1. Code works perfectly on Windows, but omits the symbols on g++ (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0

String:       Latin1: APOST ( ‘ ) QUOTE ( “ ) ( « » )
Windows: Latin1: APOST ( ' ) QUOTE ( " ) ( < > )
Ubuntu:     Latin1: APOST (  ) QUOTE (  ) (   )

Hex representation of converted strings:

```
HW: 41 50 4F 53 54 20 28 20 27 20 29 20 51 55 4F 54 45 20 28 20 22 20 29 20 28 20 3C 20 3E 20 29
HU: 41 50 4F 53 54 20 28 20    20 29 20 51 55 4F 54 45 20 28 20    20 29 20 28 20    20    20 29

  const unsigned char utf8[] = { 0x41, 0x50, 0x4f, 0x53, 0x54, 0x20, 0x28, 0x20, 0xe2, 0x80, 0x98, 0x20, 0x29, 0x20, 0x51, 0x55, 0x4f, 0x54, 0x45, 0x20, 0x28, 0x20, 0xe2, 0x80, 0x9c, 0x20, 0x29, 0x20, 0x28, 0x20, 0xc2, 0xab, 0x20, 0xc2, 0xbb, 0x20, 0x29, 0x00 };

  boost::locale::generator loc_g;
  std::string ansi0 = boost::locale::conv::from_utf<char>((const char*)utf8, loc_g.generate("Latin1"));

  printf("Latin1: %s", ansi0.c_str());
```

How to get on Ubuntu result that is similar to Windows?

Results on Ubuntu using iconv

```
ASCII:      APOST ( ' ) QUOTE ( " ) ( << >> )
Latin1:     APOST ( ` ) QUOTE ( " ) ( . . )
ISO-8859-1: APOST ( ` ) QUOTE ( " ) ( . . )
```

Comment: Did you validate with a debugger that `ansi0` really does not contain the expected characters? Maybe the Ubuntu console just can't display them?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well, actually that string is sent over network and written to log file, and symbols are missing everywhere. I'll try to check in debugger, but it also will print to console :) I'll just print the hex values.

Comment: so, you have even more layers where data loss could occur. Why are you converting UTF-8 data to a lossy charset like Latin1 in the first place? Especially over a network, you should be sending UTF-8 instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That's not three more layers, but three different layers that for some reason decided not to support Latin1 symbols. The most simple and obvious reason that the problem is in the only common layer they have, from_utf call. I have added hex values, string on Ubuntu misses 4 symbols

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because UTF-8 is not supported.

Comment: The first two Unicode chars you are losing, `‘` (U+2018) and `“` (U+201C), do not exist in Latin-1. They require transliteration to their ASCII equivalents (U+0027 and U+0022, respectively). So it would seem Boost is dropping them on Ubuntu instead of transliterating them like it does on Windows. The other two chars, `«` (U+00AB)  and `»` (U+00BB), do exist in Latin-1, and Boost should not be dropping them. So I would consider this a Boost bug. Have you tried other Unicode conversion libraries yet, like [libiconv](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I only tried to use std::codecvt, but it has even bigger problems. Libraries are my next move.

Comment: I just noticed that Boost is transliterating `«` and `»` to `<` and `>` on Windows, which is not necessary since they do exist in Latin-1. It looks like Boost is transliterating the entire UTF-8 string to ASCII instead of to Latin-1 (secondary Boost bug?). Also, the `how` method of `from_utf()` defaults to `skip`, which would explain why chars are being dropped. If you set `how` to `stop` instead, you should get a `conversion_error` exception. Also, you don't need `boost::locale::generator`, you can pass `"Latin1"` directly to `from_utf()` (have you tried passing `"ISO-8859-1"` yet?)

Comment: @RemyLebeau yeah, I have tried that and it didn't work. iconv seems to work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau updated the post with iconv results